# Combine Multiple cells with same value as one cell for average in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, max, average, min, array-formulas

I'm using large data sets to create min/max and averages.

Most specifically, when finding the average for performance reasons. I have some values that are the same up to 50 times. I don't want 50 columns or 50 rows of the same value. Is it possible to combine one cell as 50 of the same value to use in an average?

I've looked on Google, and other websites and I haven't found anything that is relative to what I'm looking for. I'm not looking reformat all the data unless its the only way.

For instance:

```
959, 10000 (x50), 12000 (x9), 12100, 15500
```

I did multiple values already but 4-5 data sets have up to 55 of the same data values.
I feel the min and max will change be not be difficult because multiple values are omitted.

Is there a value I can give to that single cell for google sheets to recongize it as 50 of that value?

Any help could be appreciated?

Link example of a data sheet that is considerably smaller than mine, want to use 1 cell for 14k etc. if possible.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R9qwnrfqzjMn6QQURDPZni8FE-H45OWB3Tvog8VRIfE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I shared an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try average of unique set:

```
=AVERAGE(UNIQUE(A:A))
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(ISNUMBER(C:D), "♦"&C:D&" 1", IF((C:D<>"")*
 (NOT(ISNUMBER(C:D))), "♦"&REGEXREPLACE(C:D, "[()]", ), ))),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")), " "), 
 "select Col1*Col2 label Col1*Col2 ''", 0))/
 SUM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(ISNUMBER(C:D), "♦"&C:D&" 1", IF((C:D<>"")*
 (NOT(ISNUMBER(C:D))), "♦"&REGEXREPLACE(C:D, "[()]", ), ))),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")), " "), 
 "select Col2", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

#### MAX/MIN

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(C:D),,99^99)),,99^99), " ")), "where not Col1 contains '-'", 0)))
```